# VisualStudio のブレークポイントの表示について

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio Community for Macを利用しています。
ブレークポイントを設定すると、以下の画像のように中身が空の表示がたまにされるのですが、これは何を示していて、どんな条件で表示されるのでしょうか。
この表示になると、ブレークポイントで止まってくれず、かといって切り替えることもできないので困っています。

すいません。画像に３種類のブレークポイントが表示されてましたね。
私がわからないのは、画像で言うと４８行目の部分です。

[image: su]

Comment: ちなみに気休め程度ですが、使っている言語/対象システムは何か、48行目で行っている処理は何かとか、ローカルデバッグかリモートデバッグか等の情報があると、相応しい回答が出てき易いかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

指定したブレークポイントが「中空」の円になる理由とは、

・デバッガーが、指定されたブレークポイントの位置をロード済みの実行コード内に発見できなかった。

ということだと考えます。
この現象が起こる理由はいくつか考えられます。

(1)指定された行には実行できるコードが無かった(可能であれば移動されることもある)。
(2)デバッグ情報(ファイル)とデバッグで実行中のコードに矛盾があるため発見できない。
(3)対象実行コードががまだロードされていないため、有効にできない。

又は、デバッガーのバグの可能性も排除できません。対策としては

(A)完全なリビルドを行ってみる。

くらいしか思い付きません。

Answer (score 1):

恐らく **無効にしたブレークポイント** ではないでしょうか。削除と追加を繰り返すよりも無効にするだけなら簡単に元に戻すことができます。

参考:
[Visual Studio デバッガーでブレークポイントを使用する。| Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019)
(リンク先は機械翻訳なので若干日本語がおかしいですが…)

> 削除しなくても、ブレークポイントを無効にポインターを合わせるかを右クリックして選択ブレークポイントを無効にするします。 左の余白に空の点として無効になっているブレークポイントが表示されます、またはブレークポイントウィンドウ。 ブレークポイントを再度有効にするには、ポインターを合わせるかを右クリックして選択ブレークポイントを有効にするします。

Comment: それって画像でいう灰色の部分のことですよね。すいません、私がわからないのは画像で言うと４８行目の部分です